# Polymer 3 refresh component

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, polymer

Ia m using polymer 3 to build my app and every things are fine with it but the problem i am facing for the past tow days is that i have a lot of ajax call on my pages and i want to call all ajax every time i open the component i read all life  life cycle callbacks of the component but it fires one  time, because Polymer is a single page app.How can i achieve that.

I tried :

```
connectedCallback() {
  super.connectedCallback();
  alert("welcome");
}
disconnectedCallback() {
  super.disconnectedCallback();
  alert("bye");
}
```

and also :

```
ready(){}
attached(){}
constructor(){}
```

and this how i move from page to page :

```
window.history.pushState({USERID_GUID:item.USERID_GUI}, "caht 1 page", '/mychatpage');
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('location-changed'));
```

Comment: It depends on how your page navigation system is implemented, but it could be that it only hide the other part of the app instead of dismounting it, hence connectedCallback will be called only one time since hide/show simply won't retrigger it.

Comment: thanks for the response i solve it

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, I decided to create my own component based on the LitElement, that will trigger the events every time you change pages

```sh
yarn add @conectate/ct-router

# or

npm i @conectate/ct-router
```

check the documentation:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@conectate/ct-router